# Rails test error - ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `country_select'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am making a signup form with country_selector gem.
The form works perfectly fine, but my tests are throwing up errors:

```
ERROR["test_should_get_new", UsersControllerTest, 1.27725670899963]
 test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (1.28s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `country_select' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000009488a88>
            app/views/users/new.html.erb:49:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___2472929520155022240_77816800'
            app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___2472929520155022240_77816800'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 1.3120288120117038]
 test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1.31s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `country_select' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000009688220>
            app/views/users/new.html.erb:49:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___2472929520155022240_78887340'
            app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___2472929520155022240_78887340'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

ERROR["test_valid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 1.3455659089959227]
 test_valid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1.35s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `country_select' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x0000000542f798>
            app/views/users/new.html.erb:49:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___2472929520155022240_44232140'
            app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___2472929520155022240_44232140'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

I am unsure why this gem doesn't seem to be accessible in the test environment. Here is my Gemfile, with country_select at the bottom of the main gems list:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '5.0.0.1'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.11'
gem 'faker',                   '1.6.6'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.5.1'
gem 'fog',                     '1.38.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.6'
gem 'puma',                    '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',                '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.4.1'
gem 'country_select',          '3.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',   '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

The tests with errors in them:

users_controller_tests.rb:

```
test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
end
```

users_signup_test.rb:

```
test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { first_name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { first_name: "Natalie", last_name: "Klein", email: "klien@example.com", city: "Melbourne", post_code: "3000", country: "Australia", self_summary: "Blah blah whatever whatever", password: "foobar1", password_confirmation: "foobar1" } }
    end
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
  end
```

Edit: Here is users/new.html.erb.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :city %>
      <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :post_code %>
      <%= f.text_field :post_code, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :country %>
      <%= f.country_select :country, priority_countries: ["AU", "US", "GB", "CA", "NZ"], class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does your view look like?

Comment: Added the code for that above.

Comment: Do you use a tool like `spring` or `guard`? Did you restart them after changing the `Gemfile`?

Comment: I use spring and I restarted the server. Still get the same errors. :/

Comment: maybe try a `require 'country_select'` at the top of your `users_signup_test.rb` spec file